# Does Rails create sessions for web crawlers and bots?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm interested in knowing whether a session is created by pages requested by web crawlers and bots. I am using MySQL as a the session store and would like to prevent requests by web crawlers and bots from creating unnecessary session entries.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using MySQL as the session store rather than using cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Since your server creates sessions, every request to it, would create a session :)